# Crystal Report Fomula in group with condition wont add the total correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

Hi ive been doing this for couple of nights now and also searching for a correct solution on web.
[image]

as you can see on the picture above i want to add the total of the group but then at the first group it is correct which is if the user is paid it will count the totalAmount if unpaid AmountPaid now the problem is on the next group it should be 23210 but it sum up above. here is my formula.

```
Global NumberVar total;
if{dsNewOrder.PaymentStatus}="PAID" then
total:=total+{dsNewOrder.TotalAmount}
else if {dsNewOrder.PaymentStatus}="UNPAID" then
total:=total+{dsNewOrder.AmountPaid}
```

i think the problem is on Global NnumberVar total it doesnt clear.
[image]

i added the CR design.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this 
Global NumberVar total:=0;
Rest formula same